# laravel how to call action in Console\Commands

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel.

And I have a controller action, which get the orders' information by date. and sum all the amount of orders, and it will return datas.

And I want to call it in `Console\Command` script so **I don't need to repeat the same code**, just get those datas from action.

Please help me how to do it?

Comment: Hey can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

Without parameters:

```php
\App::call('App\Http\Controllers\MyController@actionName')
```

If you have Request parameters:

```php
$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request($datas);
$controller = app()->make(MyController::class);
$Response = $controller->callAction('ActionName',[$request]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to call the `CreateNewUser` action from the `FortifyServiceProvider`. It took me some time to find out, but it is quite simple:

```php
use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;

// Use fortify to create a new user.
$new_user_action = new CreateNewUser();
$user = $new_user_action->create($input);
```